# RestEasy @ApplicationPath using a pattern

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to use RestEasy and Jax-Rs to route requests to the proper resources in a Java application. However, I am having trouble with using the @ApplicationPath annotation. I want to pass in a pattern and have it route anything matching that pattern to the proper place

I have tried this:

```
@ApplicationPath("*/rest/v1/")...
```

and I could route a path such as:

```
/MyApplication/rest/v1/
```

or

```
/AnotherApp/rest/v1/
```

to the same application.

However, RestEasy gives me a 404 that it can't match the resource, but if I hardcode a path without the */ it works fine. Is it possible to put a pattern like this in the @ApplicationPath?

EDIT:

The whole purpose of this was to make the root path of the application configurable and having it run through a filter to check the configuration. But if there is perhaps a way of configuring the @ApplicationPath at runtime that would be an even better solution.

Answer (score 1):

`@ApplicationPath` is an application level prefix, i.e., all paths will need to start with the given value.

For individual resources use `@Path`.

> The @Path annotation is not limited to simple path expressions. You also have the ability to insert regular expressions into @Path's value. For example:

```
@Path("/resources)
public class MyResource {

   @GET
   @Path("{var:.*}/stuff")
   public String get() {...}
}
```

> The following GETs will route to the getResource() method:

```
GET /resources/stuff
GET /resources/foo/stuff
GET /resources/on/and/on/stuff
```

> The format of the expression is:

```
"{" variable-name [ ":" regular-expression ] "}"
```

> The regular-expression part is optional. When the expression is not provided, it defaults to a wildcard matching of one particular segment. In regular-expression terms, the expression defaults to
> "([]*)"

> For example:

```
 @Path("/resources/{var}/stuff")
```

> will match these:

```
GET /resources/foo/stuff
GET /resources/bar/stuff
```

> but will not match:

```
GET /resources/a/bunch/of/stuff
```

The link: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, but I understood that much. I am just trying to create a global application path for the `@Path` resources. So each @Path has a `@ApplicationScoped` as well. So for example, I want to do: `@ApplicationPath("/.../")` and then `@Path("/stuff")` so that a url with `/.../stuff` will reach the resource denoted by `@Path("/stuff")`

Comment: I ended up creating a Web-Filter that caught all requests and left the @ApplicationPath(/). In the filter I then did various validations and then passed the request on with a modified uri to take out the basePath. I hope that might be useful to someone in the future so if it is necessary to change the baseUrl at runtime, that is probably the easiest way of doing it.